# How to combine wildcards and spaces (quotes) in an Windows command?

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards

I want to remove directories of the following format:

```
C:\Program Files\FogBugz\Plugins\cache\PluginName@example.com_NN
```

`NN` is a number, so I want to use a wildcard (this is part of a post-build step in Visual Studio). The problem is that I need to combine quotes around the path name (for the space in `Program Files`) with a wildcard to match the end of the path. I already found out that `rd` is the remove command that accepts wildcards, but where do I put the quotes? I have tried no ending quote (works for `dir`), `...example.com*"`, `...example.com"*`, `...example.com_??"`, `...cache\"PluginName@example.com*`, `...cache"\PluginName@example.com*`, but none of them work.

(How many commands to remove a file/directory are there in Windows anyway? And why do they all differ in capabilities?)

Comment: I usually use `rm -rf` for this. There are several ports of Unix coreutils to Windows: [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/), [the MSYS package of MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), Cygwin (yecch), Micros~1 own [Services for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Services_for_unix)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rmdir` *does not support* wildcards. It only accepts complete filenames.

You can try this alternative:

```
for /d %f in ("C:\Program Files\FogBugz\Plugins\cache\PluginName@example.com_*") do rmdir /s/q "%~f"
```

(The `/s/q` arguments to `rmdir` do the same thing as `rm -rf` on Unix. The `for /d` argument makes `for` match directory names instead of file names.)

---

*Remember that the `cmd.exe` shell does not do wildcard expansion (unlike Unix  `sh`) -- this is handled by the command itself.*

Comment: Your alternative works in `cmd.exe`, but not as a VS post-build step (`The command exited with code 255`). And indeed, from the (conflicting) info om the web, I thought that `rd` did support wildcards, and `rmdir` didn't. But it appears they are synonyms? And indeed, I was expecting expansion by the shell, not the individual commands.

Comment: @Jan: That might be because `for` is a `cmd.exe` built-in. You could try putting it in a `.cmd` script and run that instead. (Beware: `for` inside batch scripts requires `%%x` instead of `%x`.) And yes, `rd` and `rmdir` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the space with the `^` character:
`C:\Program^ Files\FogBugz\Plugins\cache\PluginName@example.com_*`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work (although it should: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcc7tke7(VS.80).aspx ). I use the following code: `rmdir /s /q C:\Program^ Files\FogBugz\Plugins\cache\$(TargetName)*` in VS or in `cmd.exe` (with `TargetName` replaced of course), and I get `The system cannot find the file specified. / The system cannot find the path specified.` in both places.